# std::cout is decreasing CPU Usage?

Tags: c++

I'm running a program written in C++ where CPU Usage is an important factor, and have been working to decrease it until I came across an unexpected anomaly. The program uses a `std::cout` line to view performance, and when I remove it the CPU Usage of the program spikes dramatically in the Windows Resource Monitor for about 1 second at 4-6 second intervals.

With the `std::cout` line in place, it runs smoothly at 0-2% CPU Usage without any spiking. Removing the `std::cout` line, it runs at 0-2% CPU Usage, with the 4-6 second interval CPU Usage spiking as high as 25% within the Windows Resource Monitor.

Interestingly enough, increasing the size of the string being outputted reduces the height of the CPU Spike, and reducing the size of the string increases the height of the CPU Spike.

Here are the lines of code in question:

```
float engineCompletionTime = engineTimer->getEngineCompletionTime();

/* Stops CPU from spiking */
std::cout << "Engine cycle took " << engineCompletionTime << " milliseconds." << std::endl;

if (engineCompletionTime < 14.0f) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((int)(14.0f - engineCompletionTime)));
}
```

Edit: Thank you for your initial responses, but just to be clear:

When the std::cout line is in the program, there is no CPU Spike.

When the std::cout line is not in the program, there is a CPU Spike.

As the size of the string being printed by std::cout increases, the size of CPU spike decreases.

Comment: The `std::cout` is an I/O operation, so it requires hardware interrupts to inform completion, and so takes longer time relatively. I think it is the spike you said. In fact, it does not take CPU cycles, but CPU blocks and waits until I/O operation finishes.

Comment: Try changing `std::endl` for `'\n'`. Using `endl` flushes the buffer, and if done a lot, like in a loop, can cause I/O to become a bottleneck.

Comment: `Windows Resource Monitor` is generally a horrible tool to use to gauge CPU usage of a single small application (running among hundreds of potential windows services that can wake at any time). It is generally better to use a profiler to spot any areas within your code that can be further optimized.

Comment: You're breaking quantum superposition by printing out engine completion time. Although the question is confusing: first you say you observe cpu spike only when *not* printing out, but then you say that the spike is smaller when printing a larger string.

Comment: Given that there is *no* CPU spike when printing a string, how can the size of the string affect the size of this non-existent spike?

Comment: Not including it causes the spike to be at the maximum at 25% CPU Usage.
Adding it lowers the CPU Usage based on the size of the string being outputted.
When the string is of the size that is being outputted in the code above, no noticeable spike is observed.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the implementation, writing to `std::cout` basically involves handing control over to the operating system for a short while, which then sends the data to the terminal. This isn't the fastest process on windows, and during that time the program is basically idle. The more data `std::cout` has to process, the longer the delay takes, so the more time is spent idle by the program.

A program has low CPU usage if it spends a lot of time waiting around for input (either from another program, from the keyboard or mouse, from a "redraw the screen" signal if it has a GUI, from the operating system, or from the file system). Basically, the CPU usage represents the portion of the time that the program *isn't* waiting around.

If the program's only job is to process a lot of incoming data, with no delays, then it shouldn't be waiting around at all, and it's fine if there's a high CPU usage. On the other hand, if you have a program that *is* waiting around for user input (like an application that's interactive), having a high CPU usage can be problematic because it means the program is doing a lot of work, even when the user isn't doing anything.

Making the program more efficient will generally fix this problem.

#### Other reasons for high CPU usage

If you're checking for something to happen in a tight loop, instead of using event handling, that will cause high CPU usage because even though the program's waiting for something, it's *actively checking for it*. It's the difference between checking the door for a package every three minutes, and just waiting until the doorbell rights. If you check every three minutes, you'll be doing a lot of work even though you're just waiting. But if you just wait until the doorbell rings (as with event handling), you're not actually doing any work.

Comment: What you said about it having lower CPU usage during an idle state from the std::cout makes sense, the Windows Resource Monitoring tool would be reading it as not using CPU because the program would be considered idle during the std::cout. But then what causes the CPU spike when the std::cout isn't in the program? I would expect if this were the problem, the CPU spike would be even greater with the std::cout, because the program would be being set to an idle state and then a busy state? This also doesn't address how the size of the std::cout output affects the CPU Spike

Answer (score 0):

std::cout is not exactly highly performant (especially on Win32!), and forcing a flush with std::endl isn't going to help matters :)
It's usually best to keep track of those log messages yourself, and either: write into a file when done, print an average to cout every N or so times, or print a reduced summary at the end.